# Vectorizing the conversion of columns in a 2D numpy array to byte strings

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray

**Background**

I have a 2D numpy array which represents a large number of grid-coordinate vectors, and each of these coordinate vectors need to be converted to byte strings so they can be converted into a python set.

This byte-string conversion process is a real bottleneck in my code's run-time, so I'm looking for ways to speed it up.

**Example code**

```
from numpy import int16
from numpy.random import randint
# make an array of coordinate vectors full of random ints
A = randint(-100,100,size = (10000,5), dtype=int16)
# pull each vector out of the array using iteration and convert to byte string
A = [v.tobytes() for v in A]
# build a set using the byte strings
S = set(A)
```

**Timing tests**

Using `timeit` to test the current code we get

```
setup = 'from numpy import int16; from numpy.random import randint; A = randint(-100,100,size = (10000,5), dtype=int16)'
code = 'S = set([v.tobytes() for v in A])'
t = timeit(code, setup = setup, number=500)
print(t)
>>> 1.136594653999964
```

Building the set after the conversion is less than 15% of the total computation time:

```
setup = 'from numpy import int16; from numpy.random import randint; A = randint(-100,100,size = (10000,5), dtype=int16); A = [v.tobytes() for v in A]'
code = 'S = set(A)'
t = timeit(code, setup = setup, number=500)
print(t)
>>> 0.15499859599980482
```

It's also worth noting that doubling the size of the integers to 32 bit has only a small effect on the run time:

```
setup = 'from numpy import int32; from numpy.random import randint; A = randint(-100,100,size = (10000,5), dtype=int32)'
code = 'S = set([v.tobytes() for v in A])'
t = timeit(code, setup = setup, number=500)
print(t)
>>> 1.1422132620000411
```

This leads me to suspect that most of the time here is being eaten up in overhead of either the iteration or the function call to `tostring()`.

If that's the case, I'm wondering **is there a vectorized way of doing this that avoids the iteration?**

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need strings in the first place? Why won't a set of integers work?

Comment: @Alexander Because what's being pulled out of the 2D array isn't integers, it's 1D numpy arrays (which represent a set of grid coordinates) which then get converted to strings. The 1D numpy arrays themselves aren't hashable so cannot go in the set without some type of conversion.

Comment: I thought so, but was confused with the `randint`.  In any case, I assume you want to store the coordinates with some level of fixed precision, e.g. six decimal places?

Comment: @Alexander I say coordinates but I suppose these are really vectors of *indices*, so they will be strictly 1D arrays of integers, having a length of however many dimensions there are to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized method using `np.frombuffer` -

```
# a : Input array of coordinates with int16 dtype
S = set(np.frombuffer(a,dtype='S'+str(a.shape[1]*2)))
```

Timings on given sample dataset -

```
In [83]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = randint(-100,100,size = (10000,5), dtype=int16)

In [128]: %timeit set([v.tobytes() for v in a])
2.71 ms ± 99.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [129]: %timeit set(np.frombuffer(a,dtype='S'+str(a.shape[1]*2)))
933 µs ± 4.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [130]: out1 = set([v.tobytes() for v in a])

In [131]: out2 = set(np.frombuffer(a,dtype='S'+str(a.shape[1]*2)))

In [132]: (np.sort(list(out1))==np.sort(list(out2))).all()
Out[132]: True
```

Comment: This looks really promising, but the two sets produced by the two different methods are not the same it seems, when I do `out1 == out2` it comes back false, and you can also print `[x in out1 for x in out2]` and see a bunch of falses come back. What confuses me though is that your test where you turn each in to a list and sort does return True for me as well - am I missing something that's going on here?

Comment: @CBowman Does the order matter to find out the unique strings?

Comment: When comparing two sets the order of the elements inside them is ignored, so as long as `out1` and `out2` contain the same objects, regardless of ordering, `out1 == out2` should return True, but it currently returns False. The only way this can happen is if the collection of objects held by each set is different somehow. I think it has to do with frombuffer producing objects of the 'numpy.bytes_' class, whereas ndarray.tobytes() produces object of the 'bytes' class. I might be able to work around the difference though!